# No logging for a Clojure app deployed as a WAR to Jetty

Tags: deployment, clojure, jetty, war, pedestal

I built a WAR file and deploy to Jetty 9 with [these WAR-making and deployment steps](https://gist.github.com/xpe/9857387), which is an adaptation from Pedestal's suggestions. This process has worked for me in the past, but at present, Jetty will not start the application.

I also cannot find any useful logs. This is my main problem. I have looked in these places:

- `/var/log/jetty/current` tells me only this:

```
2014-03-29_16:23:24.058:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@181d4997{/,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-myapp.war-_-myapp.domain.com-5203978721479585979.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE,myapp.domain.com}{/opt/myapp/myapp.war}
2014-03-29_16:23:24.14610 2014-03-29 16:23:24.126:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@5cb1d518{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
```

- `/opt/jetty/logs` - contains no files at all
- `/opt/myapp` - contains `myapp.war` but no logs

I also tried adding `-DDEBUG=true -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=DEBUG` to my Jetty JVM options at start-up, but the extra logging in `/var/log/jetty/current` didn't tell me what went wrong with the WAR file launch.

Although logging works in development (e.g. with `lein run-dev`), I would not be surprised if I have made some kind of mistake with my logging configuration. I'm using the standard [logback.xml](https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal/blob/master/service-template/src/leiningen/new/pedestal_service/logback.xml) provided by the Pedestal service template.

With regards to the underlying application error, I have some guesses there too. It is most likely due to recent changes in the application dependencies (I added Datomic) or connecting to Datomic at start-up.

Here is my [my project.clj](https://gist.github.com/xpe/9857556):

```
(defproject myapp-service "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "A web app"
  :url "http://myapp.domain.com"
  :dependencies
  [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
   [org.clojure/tools.reader "0.8.3"]
   [com.datomic/datomic-pro "0.9.4699"
    :exclusions [org.slf4j/slf4j-api org.slf4j/slf4j-nop commons-codec]]
   [io.pedestal/pedestal.service "0.2.2"
    :exclusions [com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core]]
   [io.pedestal/pedestal.service-tools "0.2.2"
    :exclusions [com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core]]
   [enlive/enlive "1.1.5"]
   [validata "0.1.5"]]
  :repositories
  {"my.datomic.com"
   {:url "https://my.datomic.com/repo"
    :username "email@domain.com"
    :password "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"}}
  :profiles
  {:dev
   {:source-paths ["dev"]
    :dependencies
    [[io.pedestal/pedestal.jetty "0.2.2"]]}}
  :min-lein-version "2.0.0"
  :resource-paths ["config", "resources"]
  :aliases
  {"run-dev" ["trampoline" "run" "-m" "myapp-service.server/run-dev"]}
  :repl-options
  {:init-ns user
   :init
   (try
     (use 'io.pedestal.service-tools.dev)
     (require 'myapp-service.service)
     ; HACK: Allow referencing non clojure.core symbols in :init
     (eval '(init myapp-service.service/service
             #'myapp-service.service/routes))
     (catch Throwable t
       (println "ERROR: There was a problem loading"
                "io.pedestal.service-tools.dev")
       (clojure.stacktrace/print-stack-trace t)
       (println)))
   :welcome (println
              "Welcome to pedestal-service!"
              "Run (tools-help) to see a list of useful functions.")}
  :main ^{:skip-aot true} myapp-service.server)
```

So, to restate my main question, how do I get logging to work? Everything else will follow from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassingly, my issue was DNS. Logging is fine.